# Kendo listview filterable server side filter field return null

Tags: listview, model-view-controller, filter, kendo-ui, server-side

I have mobile listview and try filtering datasource by server side with mvc controller, but filter return null.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 30,
        page: 1,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: { 
            read:  {
                url: '/Mobile/GetExecuteAssignment',
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false

            }
        },
        parameterMap: function (options) {
            var parameters = {
                filter: options.filter.filters[0].value,
                take: options.take,
                skip: options.skip,
                pageSize: options.pageSize,
                page: options.page

            };
            return parameters;
        },
```

My controller:

```
 public object GetExecuteAssignment(int page, int pageSize, string filter) {
```

}

What is the problem?
Any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

`parameterMap` is a [property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) of the transport object.

If you update your javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


    function mobileListViewFiltering() {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            pageSize: 30,
            page: 1,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Home/GetExecuteAssignment',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false

                },
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    console.log(options);

                    var parameters = {
                        filter: options.filter ? options.filter.filters[0].value : '',
                        take: options.take,
                        skip: options.skip,
                        pageSize: options.pageSize,
                        page: options.page

                    };
                    return parameters;
                }
            }
          }

        });

        $("#filterable-listview").kendoMobileListView({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            template: $("#mobile-listview-filtering-template").text(),
            filterable: {
                field: "name",
                operator: "startswith"
            },
            endlessScroll: true
        });
    }

</script>
```

You can then run type in you mobile list view and see in your browsers debugging tools that the correct paramaters are being passed (in this case, I see `filter=Jane&take=30&skip=0&pageSize=30&page=1&_=1426533857671`)

This example was adapted directly from the [filtering](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/filtering) demo.

Comment: But if i need filterable field, which is not a constant like a "Jane" , that is come from input and will change a lot! Thank you for help!

Comment: Updated code to show this working.  The mobile list view itself will take care of passing the value back to the data source.   Decent demo of this at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/filtering